# Additive and preadditive categories

Tags: category-theory, definition, additive-categories

I have been attempting to make sense [additive categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_category) recently. I outline my current understanding below and would be very grateful if you could let me know if I have made a mistake, since I am not feeling particularly confident that I have grasped this properly. My main source is the following [set of online notes](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Emozgovoy/2014_seminar/talks/AbelCat.pdf).

---

A [*preadditive category*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category) is a category $\mathcal{C}$ in which

(i) Each morphism set $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ comes endowed with the structure of an abelian group, whose identity we denote by $0_{XY}$.

(ii) Each composition map $$(f,g)\mapsto g\circ f:\text{Hom}(X,Y)\times\text{Hom}(Y,Z)\to\text{Hom}(X,Z)$$ is biadditive i.e. $(f_1+f_2)\circ g=f_1\circ g+f_2\circ g$ and $f\circ(g_1+g_2)=f\circ g_1+f\circ g_2$.

(iii) There exists an object $0$ for which $\text{Hom}(0,0)$ is the trivial group. We call any such object a [*zero object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects).

It follows directly from the definition that for each zero object $0$, the abelian groups $\text{Hom}(0,X)$ and $\text{Hom}(X,0)$ are also trivial. Then if $0$ and $0'$ are zero objects, we have that the group identity $0_{00'}$ is the unique isomorphism in $\text{Hom}(0,0')$. Since all zero objects are canonically isomorphic to each other, we may speak of **the** zero object $0$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

An *additive category* is a preadditive category $\mathcal{C}$ where for each pair of objects $X_1$ and $X_2$ there exists an object $X$ and morphisms $\pi_k:X\to X_k$, $\iota_k:X_k\to X$  ($k=1,2$) satisfying $$\pi_k\circ\iota_k=1_{X_k},$$ $$\pi_k\circ\iota_l=0_{X_lX_k},$$ and $$\iota_1\circ\pi_1+\iota_2\circ\pi_2=1_X.$$ We call any such collection a [*biproduct*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct) of $X_1$ and $X_2$. If $(X',\pi_1',\pi_2',\iota_1',\iota_2')$ is any other such collection, then $\iota_1'\circ\pi_1+\iota_2'\circ\pi_2$ is a canonical isomorphism in $\text{Hom}(X,X')$, allowing us to identify $X$ and $X'$ and we may speak of **the** biproduct of $X_1$ and $X_2$, which we write as $X_1\oplus X_2$.

---

Since they are part of the structure of the biproduct, **shouldn't the projections $\pi_k$ and inclusions $\iota_k$ also be unique?** Have I missed something important?

Comment: Unique in what sense? They're not unique in an absolute sense – you can twist everything by automorphisms and get different inclusions and projections and still have a biproduct.

Comment: @ZhenLin I have seen references to '**the** projection/inclusion morphisms', which indicates some kind of uniqueness. If the actual object of the biproduct $X_1\oplus X_2$ is fixed (WLOG since all choices are canonically isomorphic), then I am trying to understand how it is reasonable to speak of **the** projection and inclusion morphisms of the biproduct

Comment: "The" means _definite_, not unique. In other words, the morphisms are chosen in advance.

Comment: @ZhenLin So are you saying that a biproduct is an object $X$ that *admits canonical* projections and inclusions? In other words, we are only choosing the object? In that case, I guess the job is done from showing that any two 'biproduct objects' $X$ and $X'$ are canonically isomorphic. I thought it was the collection of object + projections + inclusions initially, which I guess is why I thought the morphisms also had to be chosen

Comment: No, a biproduct is an object _with_ chosen projections and inclusions. (Actually, the projections determine the inclusions and vice versa, but you have to choose one or the other.) It is mathematically meaningless to "admit canonical projections and inclusions".

Comment: Maybe an example will clarify things. The full subcategory of $\textbf{Ab}$ consisting of $0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is an additive category. By choosing a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ (as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space) we may find morphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ making $\mathbb{R}$ a biproduct of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.